# Why does the first letter return an index of -1?

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to solve a problem on codewars that goes like this:[instructions and solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Nst.png)
This is my code:
As you can see the value for their T is 20 but for me it is 0, -1 being the original index.(-1 + 1 = 0)

Here is [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dixPD.png) and here is my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD7kK.png). As you can see all the corresponding values for each letter are correct except for the very first T.

```
 def alphabet_position(text):
   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   alphabet_number = ''
   for char in text:
       if char.lower() in alphabet.lower():
        alphabet_number += ' ' + str(alphabet.find(char)+1)
        
   return alphabet_number
               
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

I've tried finding the index of t by itself off of the `alphabet.find('t')` call and the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKGdI.png) I got was 19 which is correct

**Why is the index correct outside my function but not inside my function?**

**Why is it only the first T letter that is messed up?**

Comment: No images of text please. Instead, post your code as [formatted code blocks](/help/formatting)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use a dictionary? This code has unnecessary high complexity because each time you have to find character in the list which is O(n), therefore the overall complexity is O(n^2). With dictionary you can do all in O(n). It will be O(n) to create a dictionary from a list and then O(1) each time you need to find the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lower() call is in the incorrect place

```
def alphabet_position(text):
   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   alphabet_number = ''
   for char in text.lower():
       if char in alphabet:
           alphabet_number += ' ' + str(alphabet.find(char)+1)
        
   return alphabet_number
               
print(alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."))
```

**Explanation:**

With your current answer you're checking `char.lower()` in `alphabet`, but trying to find original `char` in `alphabet` and certainly "T" is not present in `alphabet`. You can also do by replacing `char` with `char.lower()` in `str(alphabet.find(char)+1)`

Comment: Why is it that text.lower() works  but not the others?

Comment: I've added an explanation:)

Comment: because "if char.lower()" isn't actually changing the letter to lowercase.  If you want to use char.lower() you'll need to do it in the line below it.... (char.lower()+1)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I think it would be much better to use a dictionary instead of just looking up values in string. For each of the *n* letters in a string you'll need to find the character in the same string which has a complexity of *O(n)*, therefore, the overall complexity of the algorithm is *O(n^2)*. But we can do it instead like so:

```
 def alphabet_position(text):
   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   alphabet_number = ''   
   alphabet_dict = {i: j for j, i in enumerate(alphabet)}

   for char in text:
       if char.lower() in alphabet_dict:
           alphabet_number += str(alphabet_dict[char])
        
   return alphabet_number
               
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

Here `enumerate()` will form majority of complexity with *O(2n)* on an average and then you will have *n* times *O(1)* for looking up values in the dictionary which overall comes up to *O(3n)* or *O(n)* asymptotically.